# jQuery AJAX POST not firing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Here is my form. It's a Stripe form:

```
<form  id = "the_form" method = "post">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "plan" value = "silver"/>

    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
        data-description=""
        data-amount="19900"
        data-locale="auto"></script>

    <input type = "hidden" name = "email" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['b_email']; ?>"/>

    <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['brand_id']; ?>"/>
</form>
```

I want to post this form data to file called **handle_stripe_push.php**. Here is my jQuery AJAX POST call:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {  

        $("#the_form").submit(function(evnt){

            console.log("Form submit event fired")

            $.post('handle_stripe_push.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
                alert(data);

            }).fail(function(err, status){

                console.log(err + " " + status)
            })
            evnt.preventDefault()
        }); 

});
```

**The problem**. This function is not even firing when I click submit on my form. I know this because "Form submit event fired" is **not** being output to my console.

I am on Google Chrome. I did an Inspect Element, checked Console - there are **no** errors being displayed.

This is driving me a little crazy, I'd appreciate your help

Comment: Do you have a jquery cdn?

Comment: No, I am using jquery I installed locally

Comment: No, as I said in my question, no errors being displayed at all :/

Comment: The stripe script is binding the submit event also, I suspect it's preventing your script from running at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the intention is for you to handle your work on the postback from Stripe after processing....

Comment: I think @cale_b is right. I tried removing the stripe script and it works fine.

Comment: I'd like to keep the Stripe part of my form of course.  there should be a clear-cut way to not have the page redirect (via AJAX) when I submit the Stripe form, no?

Comment: You may need to do some keyboard maintenance. Your semi-colon `;` key seems to only be firing about half the time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included your locally installed JavaScript library in your page? Like you included the stripe library. Try including stripe library before jquery.

E.g.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes. As I said in my question, there are no errors being displayed in my console. '$' exists in my program

Comment: Include stripe library before jquery